# If $a_n \ge 1$ for all $n$ and $a_n + a_n^{-1}$ tends to a limit as $n \to \infty$, show that an tends to a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[This is the problem that I am looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeVLp.png)

Having difficulty with the second part:

By giving an example, show that the result is false if we replace the condition $a_n \ge 1$ with $a_n \ge k$ where $0 <  k <  1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $m\in (k,1)$. Consider the sequence
$$
a_n =
\begin{cases}
m ,& n \text{ odd} \\
m^{-1} ,& n \text{ even}. \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $a_n$ does not converge, but the sequence $b_n = a_n + a_n^{-1}$ converges to $m+m^{-1}$.

Comment: Very nice example!